# When sending data to eclipse server, how do you send data of multiple beacons at once?

Tags: java, android, sql, altbeacon

I found a problem with sending beacon data to the server and then storing it in the database. It receives 4 beacon data into the database (one data at a time in the SQL statement). Here, one piece of data is a bundle of beacon.getbluetoothname and beacon.getrssi and beacon.getdistance.
I'm using an android beacon library.

my original purpose is sending beacon data to the server faster.
And my mainly problem is sending Duplicate data to DB. I want to send data evenly from four beacons.
if you put data in sndmsg() it will send to server.
server is eclipse server.and DB is mysql.(mariaDB)

I know that redundant data comes from slow Transmission speed.
i want to improve speed. is it the limit of library or beacon(plutocon's)
Is there any way to solve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJzlL.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements          
    BeaconConsumer
{
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private List<Beacon> beaconList = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView textView ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SystemRequirementsChecker.checkWithDefaultDialogs(this);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvId);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    et =  findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    Button btn =  findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    final TextView tv =  findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    msgTV = findViewById(R.id.chatTV);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (et.getText().toString() != null || !et.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                ConnectThread th =new ConnectThread();
                th.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        }
        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Exit : " + region.getId1());
        }
        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
        }
    });

    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                beaconList.clear();
                for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    beaconList.add(beacon);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {

    }
}

public void OnButtonClicked(View view){
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            for(Beacon beacon : beaconList)
            {

                textView.setText("ID : " + beacon.getBluetoothName() + " / " + "Distance : "
                        + beacon.getDistance()+ "m\n" + " rssi:"
                        + beacon.getRssi() + "txpower : " + beacon.getTxPower()  );

            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 30);
        }
    };

private Handler mHandler;
Socket socket;
private String ip = "192.168.0.3"; // IP 주소
private int port = 7000; // PORT번호
EditText et;
TextView msgTV;

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



class ConnectThread extends Thread{
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void run(){
        try{
            while (true) {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
                //입력 메시지
                String sndMsg = null;
                //String ClientID = et.getText().toString();
                for (Beacon beacon : beaconList) {
                    String rssi = Integer.toString(beacon.getRssi());
                    String dis1 = String.format("%.3f", beacon.getDistance());
                    double dis = 0.0;
                    double ratio = Double.valueOf(rssi) * (1.0) / beacon.getTxPower();

                    if (ratio < 1.0) {
                        dis = Math.pow(ratio, 10);
                    } else {
                        dis = (0.89976) * Math.pow(ratio, 7.7095) + 0.111;
                    }

                    //ClientID = et.getText().toString();
                    sndMsg = (et.getText().toString() + "," + beacon.getBluetoothName() + "," + rssi + "," + dis);

                    //데이터 송신
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                    out.println(sndMsg);

                    //데이터 수신
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    //화면 출력
                    mHandler.post(new msgUpdate(read));
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("=============", read);
                }

                socket.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// 받은 메시지 출력하는 클래스
class msgUpdate implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public msgUpdate(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }
    public void run() {
        msgTV.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: The code shown appears to store a list of the most recently ranged beacons in the last range cycle.  If the user presses a button on the UI, it uploads this list to the server.  I would think only a few visible beacons would get sent to the server with each call.  Why is this a problem?  Are you saying you want to limit the sends to only new uniquely discovered beacons?

Comment: I think the code is wrong to be satisfied my purpose. If i send  ten data using this code, and assuming four beacons a,b,c,d  , the order becomes like aaaaaabbcd . But i want to send data like abcdabcdabcd... is there a way? don't mind my code plz.. Thank you.

Comment: My purpose is sending data from 4 different beacons in a short time to use in server. but redundant data delays server operation.

Comment: You can check for redundant data by looking at the uploaded image description

Comment: The way the code is written, I do not believe it will ever send duplicate beacons to the server in a single API call.  Why do you think otherwise?  You might try adding logging of `sndMsg`.  I believe you will find what I say is true. 
Perhaps you can attach such a log snippet to this question.  to help document the problem.